# No play button in embedded Spotify playlist

Tags: wordpress, audio, spotify, playlist

I'm trying to embed music from Spotify on a Wordpress site. Tried both playlist and single tracks - experiences issues with both:

**Playlist:**
The playlist looks nice, but I'm unable to control what track to play. The only option is to start playing from the top. On pictures there's always a small play button to the left of each track, but it doesn't appear in my case. I'm using the link provided in the Spotify desktop application, which renders into a nice looking playlist in Wordpress, for instance this:
https://open.spotify.com/user/musikkpedagogikk/playlist/1zhS1MDiYYvCYil7PcNJE8

**Single tracks**
So, then I tried to place single tracks underneath each other. It is now possible to select what track to play, but each player leaves a huge blank space below, which makes it impossible to make a functional page with 5-6 tracks.

Screenshot of playlist without proper play buttons + can only select the top track
showing huge space between single track play buttons

[Screenshot of playlist without proper play buttons + can only select the top track - and another showing huge space between single track play buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmrVz.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed and you should be able to play after clicking on the track in the list.